# Automatic Hot Restart and Reload Stopped Occurring - Flutter/VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, hot-reload

I've been learning Dart/Flutter on VS Code and the Hot Restart/Reload was always automatic (if I changed a color in the code, it automatically showed up on screen). I have to manually trigger the action now. I have no idea what changed.

I'm using VS Code and iOS emulator. I can't run SDK on Android Studio right because I'm on the new mac M1 processor.

Solutions I've tried:

1. Opened other Flutter projects and verified the hot restart isn’t
   working on any of them (its not an import error like other posts have suggested)
2. I ensured that I can manually hot restart from VSCode and terminal to see changes
3. Flutter Doctor shows no errors
4. I ran Flutter Upgrade from the terminal anyway
5. I uninstalled and reinstalled Dart and Flutter from VS Code
6. I ensured VS Code’s autosave feature was on
7. I ensured VS Code’s “Dart: Flutter Hot Reload on Save” (and Restart) were both checked
8. I tried running with and without debugging
9. I restarted my computer and VS Code

Edit: I just installed Android Studio and cannot get an automatic hot reload here either. I connected it to iOS emulator, turned on automatic saving after 2 seconds of being idle, and still have to manually reload. Alternatively, I can go to the menu and click "Save All" and it will reload to update the UI (without me having to click a hot reload or restart icon). But, it's still manual.

Edit: 2/25/21: A "fix" has been introduced in the v3.20.0 beta.
https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-20/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I was finally pointed in the right direction for an answer.

Apparently, the automatic hot reload after an IDE autosave was a bug that some users found to be a useful feature. The intended functionality was to only trigger a hot reload on a manual activation. Thus, the bug (feature) was "fixed" taking this functionality away.

Feedback shown a light on the fact that some people found the bug useful and there is now an indication that this functionality will be returned in the future.

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3110

Edit: 2/25/21: A "fix" has been introduced in the v3.20.0 beta.
https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-20/

Answer (score 0):

VSCode can be buggy sometimes and this problem is arguably the most annoying. I had this happen to me last week when I decided to use a barrel file with flutter web.

Meaning, I had a folder with all the components exported and then would import only that one file, like this

[image: barell]

And then wherever I wanted all those files to be, I would add

```
import barrell.dart
```

Now this worked perfectly fine when I was working with flutter on mobile, and the second I went to flutter web my app would not hot reload.

I share this with you to say that I found out about this **by a process of elimination.** Took me a little bit, but I created a new project from the bottom up, added in each part one by one, and then I found that it was this barrell file that was messing the hot-reload up..

So my best advice is to do the same - start fresh with a new project, add back the pieces one-by-one and if you do find out what is causing the hang-up, I implore you to share it here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: Thanks, Gene, very detail oriented approach. However, if I create a brand new project and then just change the title I can't get an automatic hot restart to update on the emulator. It's all projects I have from the past, not just the one I was working on when I noticed it stopped.

Comment: I misunderstood then ! Okay, how are you running the project? Flutter Run? with Debugging?

Comment: I tried with and without debugging. I ran it from VS Code.
I just updated the post as well. Weirdly enough, I'm having the same problem in Android Studio.

Comment: Does it hot reload on save?

Comment: On both VS Code and on Android Studio it does a hot reload on a manual save. It does not do the hot reload when either software does an automatic save due to a period of inactivity.